# Apollo Client query returns null when GraphQL Playground returns data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a function that adds a user to my database and once that is successful, I execute a query to fetch that user. The query returns data in the GraphQL playground, but when executing in my client app, the query returns null. I am using a useEffect hook to execute the query once the addPartner mutation is finished and data returns. I do not understand why the query is returning null when it returns data in the playground.

The addPartner function

```js
  const handleSubmit = async (): Promise<void> => {
    ...
    await addPartner({ variables: { input: { ...form } } })
  }
```

My useEffect hook and query function

```js
const [addPartner, { data, error: addPartnerError }] = useMutation(ADDPARTNER)
const [fetchPartner, { data: partnerData, loading }] = useLazyQuery<IPartner>(GETPARTNER)

  useEffect(() => {
    checkSuccess()
    console.log(partnerData) // null
  }, [data, loading])

  const checkSuccess = () => {
    if (!addPartnerError) {
      fetchPartner({ variables: { email: form.email } })
      console.log("fetch executed") // "fetch executed"
      console.log(partnerData) // null
      if (partnerData?.getPartner != null) {
        setPartner(partnerData.getPartner)
        router.replace('/success')
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all a bit more complicated than necessary. The first thing that sticks out is that `fetchPartner` is a promise but you're not awaiting it in your `checkSuccess` function so the data will be null at first. Furthermore your `useEffect` is triggered by `loading` which it will trigger in turn via running the query.

There are several simpler patterns you can use.

1. Return the object you're inserting as a result of the mutation. This avoids having to do two network roundtrips and you get the answer right away.
2. Return the *parent* of the object you're mutating. This is better if you're inserting into a list or deleting from one since then the whole array can be refreshed and kept in the proper order.
3. Run your query as a consequence of the mutation using [refetchQueries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries). In your case:

```
const [addPartner, { data, error: addPartnerError }] = useMutation(ADDPARTNER,{
  refetchQueries: ['GETPARTNER'] 
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the simplest answer was to return the object in my graphQL resolver so I only hit the db once